# Ignore White Space in GitKraken diff view

Tags: git, gitkraken

I have GitKraken Pro, fully updated, the 'ignore whitespace' option doesn't seem to work very well. My IDE's linter makes a lot of cosmetic changes that makes diff views far more difficult to parse, visually. Is there something I can do to address this, or is there a better tool?
[image: GitKracken not ignoring whitespace]

Answer (score 9):

when looking at a file diff you can click on the "¶" icon in the top right hand corner to ignore white space:

[image]

Comment: hmm as of 2024 this only ignores leading and trailing whitespace :-(